# Style colors of Xamarin forms shell tabbar "more popup"

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms.shell

Setting the colors of the tabbar at the bottom of shell pages can be done for
TabBarBackgroundColor, TabBarForegroundColor, TabBarTitleColor, TabBarDisabledColor, TabBarUnselectedColor

If a tabbar has more elements than can fit in the view, there is a ⋮more button which opens a popup with the remaining elements. I need to change the coloring of that popup. My app is generally themed in a dark style and this popup is light gray/white, but neither inside the android (currently testing with android) styling nor inside the xaml shell styling can I find a way to change that part of the coloring. None of the tabBar properties seem to relate to this.

I assume it can be done, but where exactly?

Comment: You can try to use [ShellRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers)  to achieve this.

Comment: That sounds like a workable solution, but are you by this saying that it is not supported through more generalized means. Do you know?

Comment: Thank you for your question. 
I am trying to involve someone familiar with this topic to further look at this issue. There might be some time delay. Appreciate your patience.